# Custom View Buttons

Tags: android, class, view, android-widget

What I have here is a custom view and then I want some widgets to go with it.

```
<com.zone.manager.Tab3
    android:id="@+id/tab3_display"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="620dp" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addZone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Zone" />

</com.zone.manager.Tab3>
```

Now I want to have that button set to onclicklistener so I can do stuff with it in the View class so I did this...

```
addZone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addZone);


  addZone.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I set that in the

```
public class Tab3 extends ViewGroup implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener
    Public Tab3(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
    super (context, attrs); 
    // here
    }
```

When I extended ViewGroup it made me implement this

```
@Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Is there something that I am suppsot to put in here in order to make this work?

But when I try to run the app it crashes, however if I // out the `addZone.setOnClickListener(this);` the app runs fine, any help for me?

tabs

```
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag0");
        specs.setContent(R.id.connecttionTab);
        specs.setIndicator("Connection Tab");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("Zone Manager");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_vaccontrol));
        th.addTab(specs);
        //this is the tab that has all this vvv
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("Graphical Layout");
        th.addTab(specs);
```

Comment: When you changed to a ViewGroup, did you also change the xml so that the Button is a child element nested inside the Tab3 element? If it just follows it like the xml you posted, it still won't be found by `findViewById`. And, yes, you need to implement `onLayout` to decide where each of the child elements (in this case, just the Button) should be placed within the bounds of the parent Tab3 element.

Comment: IM sorry but I dont understand what that means. Could you explain it for me?

Comment: See my first sample xml code in my answer. Note that the first tag does _not_ end the `Tab3` element. (It ends with `>` instead of `/>`, and there is a `</com.zone.manager.Tag3>` tag _after_ the `Button` tag.) The `Button` element is a child, not a sibling, of `Tab3`.

Comment: I suggest that you use the second layout approach I suggested. I don't know what layout you want exactly, so I can't offer a specific layout for you to try. Can you explain what the layout on the screen is supposed to be (i.e., where should Tab3 be showing and where should the button be showing)? If the button is supposed to be on top of Tab3, then you could perhaps use a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout to good effect.

Comment: The button is supposed to be below Tab3 and could you edit your answer to show me what I want to do because I am very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your xml, your custom view does not *contain* the button; it is a sibling view. The reason your app crashes is that `findViewById(R.id.addZone)` is returning `null`, so you are getting a `NullPointerException` when you call `addZone.setOnClickListener(this)`. If you want your custom view to contain the button, the xml would have to look something like this:

```
<com.zone.manager.Tab3
    android:id="@+id/tab3_display"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="620dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addZone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Zone" />

</com.zone.manager.Tab3>
```

Also, your `Tab3` class will have to extend `ViewGroup`, not `View`. This can get a bit complicated because you also need to write code to do the layout. The button will also be displayed inside the `Tab3` view.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments  of what you are trying to do, I do not recommend the above approach. Instead, you should just wrap your custom view and the Button in a `LinearLayout`. For example, the following layout will put the button at the bottom left of the screen and will have a Tab3 view fill the area above it:

**res/layout.tab3.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.zone.manager.Tab3
        android:id="@+id/tab3_display"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addZone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onAddZone"
        android:text="Add Zone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, move the click processing logic to a separate method in `Tab3` that is visible to your `Activity` class. (Let's assume that it is called `addZone()`.) The `Tab3` class should not implement `OnClickListener` and should extend `View` (not `ViewGroup` as above). By adding the `android:onClick` attribute to the button, you don't need to add an `OnClickListener` to the button. Instead, you need to implement a click method of that name in the activity:

```
private Tab3 mTab3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab3);
    mTab3 = (Tab3) findViewById(R.id.tab3_display);
    // . . .
}

@Override
/**
 * Called when a view with attribute android:onClick="onAddZone"
 * is clicked.
 *
 * @param view the view that was clicked.
 */
public void onAddZone(View view) {
    mTab3.addZone();
}
```

Although there is nothing in your code about the button, the framework will automatically wire everything up using reflection so that the `onAddZone` method of the activity will be called when the button is clicked.

Comment: I updated my question, I did what you said however it is still crashing if I have `addZone.setOnClickListener` in and if I dont have it in my on draw section will not come up? Any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelZeuner - I updated my answer based on your update and comments.

Comment: When I click on the button the app crashes.

Comment: and I get an error saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onAddZone(View) in the activity class com.zone.manager.VacControl for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'addZone'

Comment: @MichaelZeuner - Well, did you add such a method to your activity class as I said to do?

Comment: yes I made a new activity and called it Tab3Activity and I put all the code you put up there in it then in Tab3 I put a public void addZone()

Comment: @Michael - But according to the error message, you are running the VacControl activity, not the Tab3Activity. You need to update your code (and probably your manifest) so that the correct activity is started.

Comment: So it works when I dont run it as a tab, however I need it to be the fourth tab, if I update my question to show you what I have for the tabs could you help me set it up to work with the tabs?

Comment: @MichaelZeuner - It might be better to start another question. It's a bit of a different problem now.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct way to extend a viewgroup while having the layout in an xml file. You need to change your xml to look like this:

**R.layout.xml_file_for_custom_view**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

       tools:parentTag="com.zone.manager.Tab3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addZone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Zone" />

</merge>
```

In your code for the custom view, you need to inflate the xml and add your onclick listener:

**Tab3.java**

```
public class Tab3 extends ViewGroup implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener
    
    public Tab3(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super (context, attrs);
        // inflate and attach the layout to this viewgroup
        View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.xml_file_for_custom_view, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        // Now you can find the button
        addZone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addZone);
        addZone.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Now whereever you use your custom view, you can now do:

```
<com.zone.manager.Tab3
    android:id="@+id/tab3_display"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="620dp"/>
```

As for your question about the `onLayout` method:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Yes you will need to put some code in there. See [this guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#developer-guides) to help you get started.